Is omitting the mixture components with small weight enough to select the number of mixture components
I had a discussion with one of my colleagues and he told me that if we fit k- mixture components and some of them are very small, then we can remove them and hence we select the number of the mixture components. But I think this is not enough as the estimation of the mixture weight strongly affected by the starting values (EM-algorithm). So, is it really good idea to fit large number of mixture components and remove any of them with small mixture weights?
